# Find cell in column that contains a specific word but also contains a number, and return that row location

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find the location of the word "Skill" in a column. The problem I am having is that the row that Contains the word "Skill" also contains a number so the cell reads something like "Skill 1498". The number in the cell changes so I can't do a match for "Skill 1498" because that number will be different.

right now all I have is:

```
=MATCH("Skill",BK:BK,0)
```

but that returns #N/A because of the number that also lives in that cell.

Comment: Use `=MATCH("Skill*",BK:BK,0)` to return the row number of the first cell that starts with *skill*.

Comment: Thanks so very much!

Comment: You always should look up the documentation for the function : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a * for any length of chars after or in the statement, ? for a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Wildcard in the text string.  This is typically an asterisk, in most computer programs.

Your formula would be:

`=MATCH("Skill" & "*",BK:BK,0)`

Jeeped's formula totally works and is probably more clear. :)